# Spring: constructor injection of primitive values (properties) with annotation based configuration

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations

I'm trying to configure a class with Annotation based configuration in Spring 3, which takes primitive values as its constructor arguments:

```
@Component
class MyBean {
  MyBean(String arg1, String arg2) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

And an application context like this:

```
<beans [...]>
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />
  <context:property-override location="/WEB-INF/example.properties" />
</beans>
```

I'm trying to find some way to specify that the constructor arguments should be taken from the properties file. Apparently this does work with constructors that take regular beans (e.g. `MyClass(Bean bean1, OtherBean bean2)`), but just properties?

I have also tried annotating the constructor arguments with Spring 3's `@Value` annotation and an EL expression for the value, like `@Value("#{prop.Prop1}") arg1`, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following code works fine with `<context:property-placeholder .../>`:

```
@Component 
public class MyBean { 
    @Autowired
    public MyBean(@Value("${prop1}") String arg1, @Value("${prop2}") String arg2) { 
        // ... 
    } 
}
```

But `<context:property-override .../>` is a very specific thing, it's not suitable here.

Comment: Will the property file have "myBean.prop1=foo" or just "prop1=foo"? That is, are the properties scoped by bean name?

Comment: Property file will have `prop1=foo`. If you need `myBean.prop1=foo`, write `@Value("${myBean.prop1}")`. It's the way how `<context:property-placeholder .../>` works.