# Spring MVC Controller Unit Testing : How do I set private instance boolean field?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I have a Spring MVC REST controller class that has a private instance boolean field injected via @Value ,

```
@Value("${...property_name..}")
private boolean isFileIndex;
```

Now to unit test this controller class, I need to inject this boolean.

How do I do that with `MockMvc`?

I can use reflection but `MockMvc` instance doesn't give me underlying controller instance to pass to `Field.setBoolean()` method.

Test class runs without mocking or injecting this dependency with value always being `false`. I need to set it to `true` to cover all paths.

Set up looks like below.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value=Controller.class,secure=false)
public class IndexControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can use [@TestPropertySource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html)**

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
    "...property_name..=testValue",
})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value=Controller.class,secure=false)
public class IndexControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

}
```

**You can also load your test properties form a file**

```
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")
```

---

**EDIT**: Some other possible alternative

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value=Controller.class,secure=false)
public class IndexControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired 
    private Controller controllerUnderTheTest;


    @Test
    public void test(){
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(controllerUnderTheTest, "isFileIndex", Boolean.TRUE);

        //..
    }

}
```

Comment: so how to change property value for  different `@Test` methods? This annotation is applicable at test class level.Primary target is not to get values from property file but to alter values for various scenarios.

Comment: @SabirKhan Then you should reload your application context with different test properties. But it should be possible also change it using reflection as is shown above. See updated post.

Comment: Yes, I had got it working with something like `controller = new IndexController();
  
  mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
  
  isFileIndexField = controller.getClass().getDeclaredField("isFileIndex");
  
  isFileIndexField.setAccessible(true);
  
  indexServiceField = controller.getClass().getDeclaredField("indexService");
  indexServiceField.setAccessible(true);
  indexServiceField.set(controller, indexService);`  but your suggestion is pretty small code.

Comment: Your answer using `ReflectionTestUtils` is working and I didn't know that I can do - `@Autowired private Controller controllerUnderTheTest;` . Seems knowing that was the key. Thanks !!

Comment: Yes, you can. It is just a Spring bean.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred option would be to set it in the constructor and annotate the constructor parameter with the `@Value`. You could then pass in whatever you want in the test.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203302/how-to-inject-a-value-to-bean-constructor-using-annotations)

Comment: I am not explicitly creating controller instance here so I think, constructor wouldn't help. Let me know if I am missing anything.