# access properties from spring file in java class

Tags: java, spring

I've been assuming stuff and seeing that now it's not correct. I have the following configuration properties declaration in my spring context :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
        <property name="searchContextAttributes" value="true" />
        <property name="contextOverride" value="true" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:/app.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I thought values from `app.properties` would override my system properties so I would be able to acess them directly in my Java classes like this :

```
String someThingFromPropertyFile = System.getProperty("nameFromPropertyFile");
```

And of course I get null pointer exceptions all over the place. Now I'm here to ask how to access your application properties from you application (Java classes part of your application).

Is there a better way than this below (I'm not saying it's bad).

[Access properties file programmatically with Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771166/access-properties-file-programatically-with-spring)

Comment: Why not just inject the property where you need it or use the utils? (I'm not sure why you'd think they'd override system properties--they're completely unrelated.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In app context :

```
 <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:your.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

then in java you can do this :

```
@Value("${cities}")
private String cities;
```

where the your.properties contains this :

```
cities = my test string
```

Answer (score 0):

`Spring` properties do not override `System` properties. It works the other way. You should be getting all your properties from `Spring` and not from `System.getProperties()`. `System` properties will override `Spring` properties with the same name. The `SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE` you are setting says that when you get a property value from `Spring` the `System` property will win.

You want to set the value to be `SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_FALLBACK`. This is the default so you don't actually need to set it.

If you have this in mind, @NimChimpsky has it the correct method for accessing property values:

```
@Value("${nameFromPropertyFileOrSystemProperty}")
private String someThingFromProperty;
```