# Access properties outside spring context

Tags: spring, properties

I have some properties configured in my spring context with `<context:property-placeholder>`. That works fine.

What is the best way to access a named property loaded like that, from outside of the spring context (where I have a reference to the spring ApplicationContext object).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771166/access-properties-file-programatically-with-spring?rq=1

Comment: I don't see the answer in that link. I need to access the properties loaded in the context without having to load them again, knowing all the resources, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing and configuring a spring Bean that has the property values injected with the @Value annotation, and then retreiving this bean from the context.

Not 100% elegant, but it works.