# Spring Boot import additional extensionless properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm running my Spring Boot application with Kubernetes. Part of the architecture involves mounting secrets as file volumes under `/opt/config`.

```
$ ls -l
SECRET_1
SECRET_2
SECRET_3
```

Each file contains a `.properties` like syntax. (`key=value`)

I've been attemtping to make Spring Boot load these as per the documentation `spring.config.import=file:/etc/config/myconfig[.yaml]`

However I just can't get this to work, my full command is: `java -Dspring.config.location=file:./opt/application.properties -Dspring.config.additional-location=file:./opt/config/*[.properties] -jar target/test.war --debug --server.port=8080`

The `./opt/application.properties` file is loaded correctly.

I have also attempted to rename all the files to include `.properties`:

```
$ ls -l
SECRET_1.properties
SECRET_2.properties
SECRET_3.properties
```

And load it via `java -Dspring.config.location=file:./opt/application.properties -Dspring.config.import=file:./opt/config/*/ -jar target/test.war --debug --server.port=8080`, however this also did not import any of the properties under `./opt/config`.

I've read through the documentation dozens of times now, and this should be working, but it's not. Did I miss something obvious? Why is it not loading any of the files under `./opt/config`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the locations you specify are where spring looks for application.properties, application.yml and profile variants (application-prod.properties, etc). I think you are better off loading all the files in a configured location programmatically, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771166/access-properties-file-programmatically-with-spring) might provide some ideas.

Comment: I don't really understand your answer. I'm looking for a way to import properties from generated files. I know how to access properties, I just can't seem to make Spring Boot import them.

Comment: I don't think the `spring.config.import` option property works the way you think it does. You could import each file individually as per `spring.config.import=file:/etc/config/SECRET_1[.properties]` from in the application.properties. I can't see however anything in the documentation that says you can wildcard the import or use `spring.config.import` on the command line.

Comment: You're right, the wildcard seems only related to `spring.config.location`. I guess I'll need to explicitly list all names for import.